# Saving text from webpage for word cloud in R

Tags: r, import, tm, rvest, word-cloud

I'm trying to practice making word clouds in R and I've seen the process nicely explained in sites like this (http://www.r-bloggers.com/building-wordclouds-in-r/) and in some videos on YouTube. So I thought I'd pick some random long document to practice myself.

I chose the script for Good Will Hunting. It is available here (https://finearts.uvic.ca/writing/websites/writ218/screenplays/award_winning/good_will_hunting.html). What I did is copy that into Notepad++ and start removing blank lines, names, etc. to try to clean up the data before saving. Saving as a .csv file doesn't seem to be an option so I saved it as a .txt file and R doesn't seem to want to read it in.

Both of the following lines return errors in R.

```
goodwillhunting <- read.csv("C:/Users/MyName/Desktop/goodwillhunting.txt", sep="", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
goodwillhunting <- read.table("C:/Users/MyName/Desktop/goodwillhunting.txt", sep="", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

My question is based on an html document what is the best way to save it to be read in to be used for something like this? I know with the rvest package you can read in webpages. The tutorials for word clouds have used .csv files so I'm not sure if that's what my end goal needs to be.

This might be a way to read in the data going that route?

```
test = read_html("https://finearts.uvic.ca/writing/websites/writ218/screenplays/award_winning/good_will_hunting.html")
text = html_text(test)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Since all you want is a list of words, you can use https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming/Text_Processing#Reading_and_writing_text_files You cannot use `read.table/csv` as the text from page is not a table.

Comment: you could try using readLines to import the document and then parse each line into your data structure.

Comment: Thank you both! I used the readLines() function and then with paste(text,collapse=" ") was able to string all of the words together and build a word cloud!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
library(rvest)
library(wordcloud)

test    <- read_html("https://finearts.uvic.ca/writing/websites/writ218/screenplays/
                      award_winning/good_will_hunting.html")

text    <- html_text(test) 
content <- stringi::stri_extract_all_words(text, simplify = TRUE)

wordcloud(content, min.freq = 10, colors = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(5,"Spectral"))
```

Which gives:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example:

```
library(wordcloud)
text = scan("fulltext.txt", character(0), strip.white = TRUE)
frequency_table = as.data.frame(table(text))
wordcloud(frequency_table$text, frequency_table$Freq)
```